# Finding the conditional probability of a transition probability matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

Let the transition probability matrix of a Markov chain, $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$, be given by
$$
P=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 / 2 & 1 / 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 / 2 & 1 / 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$

Compute $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}=6 \mid X_{1} \in\{3,4\}, X_{0}=2\right)$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}=6 \mid X_{1} \in\{3,4\}\right)$.

**My attempt**

Edited:

$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}=6 \mid X_{1} \in\{3,4\}, X_{0}=2\right)$

The only path you can take is $ 2 -> 4 -> 6 $ hence the probability is $1$.

Now for

$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}=6 \mid X_{1} \in\{3,4\}\right)$ since we don't know what $X_0$ there can be multiple probability as below:

*Path 1:*

$1 -> 4 -> 6$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$

*Path 2:*

$1 -> 3 -> 6$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$

*Path 3:*

$2 -> 4 -> 6$ with probability $1$

Am I right?

Comment: Your answer to the first probability seems to be $1/2$, which is incorrect.  I cannot follow your first equation (which seems to have some typos with expressions running into other expressions). Are you saying $P[A|B,C]=P[A|B]P[A|C]$? That is not generally true. You can reason the correct probability out from the given info $X_1 \in \{3,4\}, X_0=2$ and the structure of the chain, without any formulas.

Comment: @Michael I see what you are saying. I tried calculating the first probability again $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{2}=6 \mid X_{1} \in\{3,4\}, X_{0}=2\right)$ and I got $1*1 + 1*\frac{1}{2} = 1.5$? Am I right? As I for the second probability, I am not sure how to go about it as this is all the information I was given. But wouldn't it make sense to calculate the 2 step transition matrix for the second probability?

Comment: Probabilities cannot be larger than 1.  I strongly encourage you to draw a picture of this discrete time Markov chain. If you do, you will observe $$\{X_0=2\}\subseteq \{X_1 \in \{3,4\}\}$$

Comment: @Michael Thank you for being patient with me and explaining. I have amended my answer. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, given $X_0=2$, then we must have $X_1=4$ and $X_2=6$ (all with prob 1). So the added "information" $X_1 \in \{3,4\}$ is not telling you anything you do not already know.  On the other hand if we are just told $X_1 \in \{3,4\}$ then we do not have enough info to compute $P[X_2=6|X_1 \in \{3,4\}]$ since we do not know the probability distribution associated with the initial condition.